# Launching IE using selenium - Error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open the IE using Selenium with the help of following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;


public class seleniumtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:/Softwares/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.39.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/Softwares/chromedriver_win_17.0.963.0/chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        //driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }

}
```

Getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 80070005 for URL 'http://localhost:26504/' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'ACE-PC', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_07'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:194)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:155)
    at seleniumtest.main(seleniumtest.java:13)
```

I have just followed the below steps also but it didn't helped me:

> It needs to set same Security level in all zones. To do that follow
>   the steps below:
>
> ```
> Open IE
> Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
> Set all zones to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.
> ```

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
dc.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);  //If IE fail to work, please remove this and remove enable protected mode for all the 4 zones from Internet options
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);

Comment: If the above didn't worked let me know

Comment: Try using the latest version of IE driver. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Also create a trace log using the IEDriver, by using the [builder](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder.html#withLogLevel(org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel))

Comment: @PrashanthSams I am getting this error while using your syntax Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token at the line dc.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY‌​_DOMAINS, true);

Comment: @PrashanthSams i have tried all the above that you have mentioned, no luck :(

Comment: Are you using the latest driver from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: @PrashanthSams I am using the latest IE driver only. I have downloaded the driver from the link which you have mentioned only.

Comment: Try D:\\ instead of D:/ [make it simple and test copy it in D drive and check it]

Comment: @PrashanthSams Tried this option also not working :( error is " org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 80070005 for URL 'http://localhost:29853/' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.35 seconds"

Comment: turn ON protected mode in ALL Internet Explorer Zones (Security Tab in IE settings)

Comment: @PrashanthSams Already I have turned on all internet explorer zones

Comment: @Gokul I feel you have missed something somewhere :(

Comment: Try the same in your friends machine; you will observe; Hope I am clear

Comment: @PrashanthSams I will try in some other machine and let you know. Already I have tried in one of my friend tried in another machine and he too getting the same error.

Comment: okay please do the needul

Comment: @PrashanthSams Could you please say how to set the IE path?

Comment: just for an easy way, copy and paste your IEDriverServer.exe in C folder and specify like this in the script C:\\IEDriverServer.exe

Comment: @PrashanthSams I tried this also but did not worked. Tried in friends machine also but getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

- At times administrator has blocked the IE for changing the required protected mode settings.

  - Instead you can use the Desired capabilities feature with Selenium to launch the IE with the set capabilities.
  - In this way you are not dependent on your administrator to change the settings
  - Code shown below can be used.

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");

    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.
      INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

    String driverPath = "C:\Selenium\";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

Answer (score 0):

It works!!!
I followed the below steps:

- Open IE
- Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
- Set all zones to the same protected mode

Enabled or disabled should not matter.